# How to create new organisation in Azure and move user from old to new organisation

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How to create new organisation in Azure and move user from old to new organisation.

Eg: Move developer@example.com to new from old organisation. I want to create new organisation and migrate user(developer@example.com) to new organisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can **[export](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-bulk-download)** the users from the old tenant and **[import](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-bulk-add)** into the new tenant.

However, you can't import the password user.

Hope this help!